# How to set text decoration for "this".sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to make a text decoration of `line-through' when a checkbox is checked and remove the decoration when the checkbox is unchecked.

This is my js:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('label').style.textDecoration = "line-through";
} else {
    $(this).siblings('label').style.textDecoration = "none";
}
```

With the current code I get the error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textDecoration' of undefined

and I'm assuming it is because it doesn't like my `this.siblings` string.

Comment: Don't mix jquery and vanilla js

Comment: @thomas is that the issue or is it just a principle?

Edit: Never mind, answered that for myself. Thanks.

Comment: The issue is that jQuery isn't returning a DOM element when you call `$(this).siblings('label')` - it doesn't have a property named `style`, so you get a TypeError trying to access `style.textDecoration`.

Comment: I would not add a style, I'd use jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass` methods to add/remove a css class that you manage in the style sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this one.

```
$(this).siblings('label').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');

$(this).siblings('label').css('text-decoration', 'none');
```

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks. I didn't realize mixing js and jquery was such a big no-no..

Comment: It's not that the two can't work together - it's that jQuery returns jQuery collections, which have a different API from vanilla js DOM elements.

Answer (score 4):

If your `label` is *after* the `checkbox` input, you can use **plain CSS** and the Next Sibling operator `+`

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" name="a1"><label for="a1">UNCHECKED</label>
```

if it's not an immediate sibling than you can use the ***Sibling Operator `~`*** instead of `+`.

---

`.style` is plain JS and refers to only one element while you're handling an array of jQuery selectors Elements.

So yes, user jQuery's `.css()` method to apply the changes to all your elements (jQuery will loop all of them internally like you would in JS using `for` loop or `forEach`)

If you want you can also do it using a ***conditional operator*** `?:`  (without the `if else`) simply like:

```js
$(':checkbox').on("change", function(){
    $(this).siblings('label').css({"text-decoration": this.checked ? "line-through" : "none"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a1" name="a1"> <label for="a1">UNCHECKED</label>
</p>
```

If you want you *can* mix jQuery and JS here's an example:

```
$("#element")[0]/*or use .get(0)*/.style.textDecoration = "none";
```

but as I've said before it cannot be applied to multiple elements if not used inside a loop, passing that current index as the *get* value:

```
$(".elements").each(function(i){
   $(this)[i].style.textDecoration = this.checked ? "line-through" : "none" ;
});
```

which is a mix of jQuery and JS's:

```
for(var i=0; i<myJSelements.length; i++){
    myJSelements[i]/* etc... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `.sibling('label')` return an element or Text?

If it returns Text, then that is your problem.

Apply `.style.textDecoration` to the element.

The function identifies the text node in the element and decorates it.